# Are Ubuntu 20.04 updates failing on in.archive.ubuntu.com

Tags: apt, updates

apt-get update is failing on India location. Its not able to reach out to in.archive.ubuntu.com.

Below is the error :

```
# apt-get update 
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                  
Err:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                         
  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:ffff::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (103.97.84.254), connection timed out
Err:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:ffff::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:ffff::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:ffff::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (103.97.84.254), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:ffff::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:ffff::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Can someone please suggest / help here.

Comment: Change servers?

Comment: Let me try, using US.

Comment: US fails with this error  : Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24).

Comment: Please use the [edit] feature to add additional information to your question.

Comment: BTW, several similar reports today!

Comment: Thanks, chaging the server worked. I have posted steps to how to get around with this in my answer below (for ubuntu newbies) ... I had to do this today, as I do a weekly security updates and need to power-cycle my machine weekly. Your comment helped in urgency! Thank you DK Bose.

Comment: [in.archive.ubuntu.com is now up](https://www.isitdownrightnow.com/in.archive.ubuntu.com.html)

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to DK Bose's comment, changing server helped. It fails intermittently though, but it started working. Here is how to get around with this issue.
Run the following as root

```
cd /etc/apt
sed -i 's/in\./us\./g' sources.list
```

Below should be the output of your next apt-get update

```
# apt-get update 
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                               
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                       
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [98.3 kB]
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Fetched 205 kB in 6s (36.3 kB/s)                 
Reading package lists... Done
```

Hope this helps!

~Abhay Dandekar

Answer (score 0):

All the Indian repos are not reachable.

We can temporarily point to US or any other locale repos. But I am hoping that the Ubuntu team will look into the issue and fix it.